# How to load VBA script in all new and existing Microsoft Word Documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a VBA script for word that applies in all Documents I open, whether they're new or already existing ones.

How would I go about that, I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Depends on what you mean to accomplish. Putting your code in the `Normal.dotx` document template could do it. Putting your code in a Word add-in could do it as well. What have you tried?

Comment: What's the purpose of the code you're planning on writing?

Comment: @ashleedawg It's a macro to make the life easier.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Won't that only apply to new documents though?

Comment: An add-in works at the application level, and does whatever you need it to do - be it on new or existing documents. Again, depends on exactly what you need to do and how you intend to do it. Your question is too vague to get any better answer at the moment.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It's never Normal.dotx, it's always Normal.dotm...

Comment: @ Niclas M. Any VBA code added to a template is available to all documents based on that template. Macros added to Word's Normal.dotm template are available to all documents, regardless of whether they're based on that template.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

You put the .dotm in %AppData%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP